# java simple thread, but it can't run

Tags: java, multithreading

it's a simple java thread.

there are 2 threads, and it should be printed every 5 second.
there's no error.
but i just can't run.
please help me finding out what's wrong...

```
class MyThread extends Thread {
    String message;
    int delay;

    public MyThread(String s, int d) {
        message = s;
        delay = d;
    }
    public void run() {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(delay);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            System.out.println(message + "+" + delay );
        } 
    }
}

public class applet {  
    public static void main(String[] args){  
        MyThread mt1, mt2;

        mt1 = new MyThread("Hello", 5000);
        mt2 = new MyThread("Bye  ", 10000);
        mt1.start();
        mt2.start();
   }  
}
```

Comment: You're only printing things if an exception is raised. You will have better luck if you move the call to `println()` to after the `catch` block.

Comment: Also, you say " it should be printed every 5 second.". That's wrong. You pass a value of ``5000`` to your thread's constructor, then sleep once, then the threads end.

Comment: Please specify what "just can't run" means. But if you expect the message to be displayed: The `InterruptedException` will only be thrown if the Thread is interrupted before the sleep period expires. This will not be the case in your code. Move the `System.out.println`inside the ´try´ block,after the `sleep` call

Comment: @TedHopp you're right. I misunderstand the meaning of try&catch. thank u.

Comment: @f1sh i see. I pass pass values of `5000` and `10000` to my two thread's constructor. and they start at the same time, but ends at different time, is it right?

Comment: @ThomasStets thank u, you're right, i just learn java and not completely understand try&catch

Comment: @XinyiZhang that is correct. They end after 5 and 10 seconds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are printing **ONLY ONCE** if an exception occurs...

Modify the `run` method to:

```
public void run() {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(delay);
            System.out.println(message + "+" + delay );
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            System.err.println("error here" );
        } 
    }
```

Comment: also, just once as @f1sh commented.

Answer (score 1):

There are actually `2` mistakes in your program:

#### 1. Print your message in the normal flow

So far you only print your message when you get an `InterruptedException` which is an exception that is thrown when your thread has been interrupted while sleeping. So instead of printing your message in the catch block, you are supposed to print it after the `sleep` as next:

```
try {
    Thread.sleep(delay);
    System.out.println(message + "+" + delay );
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
    // Re-set the interrupted flag
    Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
}
```

#### 2. Add an infinite loop

As you wish to print your message every 5 seconds, you need to call `sleep` in an infinite loop otherwise your thread will print it only once and die, so the code should be at the end:

```
try {
    while (true) {
        Thread.sleep(delay);
        System.out.printf("%s+%d%n", message, delay);
    }
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
    // Re-set the interrupted flag
    Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
}
```

---

#### 3. Bonus

Alternatively, you can use a [`ScheduledExecutorService`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html) to schedule your tasks with a fixed rate using the method [`scheduleAtFixedRate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html#scheduleAtFixedRate-java.lang.Runnable-long-long-java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit-), your code would then be:

```
// Create a ScheduledExecutorService of 2 threads
ScheduledExecutorService executor = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(2);
// Schedule my task every 5 seconds starting in 5 seconds
executor.scheduleAtFixedRate(new MyTask("Hello", 5000), 5L, 5L, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
// Schedule my task every 10 seconds starting in 10 seconds
executor.scheduleAtFixedRate(new MyTask("Bye  ", 10000), 10L, 10L, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

The class `MyTask` would simply be:

```
class MyTask implements Runnable {
    String message;
    int delay;

    public MyTask(String s, int d) {
        message = s;
        delay = d;
    }
    public void run() {
        System.out.printf("%s+%d%n", message, delay);
    }
}
```

Comment: thank u. i see. now i finish it with an infinite loop. and i understand try&catch now